How draw grafana graph with metric by prefix?
Consider metrics:

airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_mysensor
airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_othersensor
airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_somesensor
...

So how to create graph with all these metrics? I have defined grafana sensor variable metrics(airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_) and applied regexp airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_(.*).
But wirting graph with airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_$sensor leads to error error near $ symbol.
The goal to see 3 line on panel but automatically because in real application there are much lines to draw
UDATED
I tried {__name__=~"airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_*"} - but this got me one line

If you have all three mentioned metrics, query ``{name=~"airflow_scheduler_operator_failures_.*"} (notice . before *) should get you expected result.
